# pthread_join() seems to lead to hang my program, where did it get wrong?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I've got a small program as a test like below:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<cassert>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
pthread_mutex_t mt;
pthread_t tid[2];
char* msg[]={"thread1","thread2"};
void* tf(void*arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
    cout<<(char*)arg<<endl;
    return NULL;
}
int main(){
    assert(0==pthread_mutex_init(&mt,NULL));
    cout<<"step1"<<endl;
    pthread_create(&tid[0],NULL,tf,msg[0]);
    pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,tf,msg[1]);
    pthread_join(tid[0],NULL);
    cout<<"step4"<<endl;
    pthread_join(tid[1],NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm running it my on mac and it prints:

```
step1
thread1
step4
```

Then it hangs and no longer runs. Where did the code get wrong?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: why not using C++'s threading capabilities?

Comment: `assert(0==pthread_mutex_init(&mt,NULL));` is a **bug**. Assertions must not have side effects, since they are normally not part of non-debug builds.

Comment: it is hanging because all threads but one cannot exit. They all wait on mutex lock. You need to release the lock in the thread before exit to let other threads to proceed. It does not matter which package to use for this. See answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `pthread_mutex_lock`:

> The mutex object referenced by mutex shall be locked by calling
>   `pthread_mutex_lock()`. **If the mutex is already locked, the calling
>   thread shall block until the mutex becomes available.**

Thread 2 is waiting forever for `mt` to unlock since you never unlock it and thread 1 locked it, you should unlock at the end of `tf` :

```
void* tf(void*arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
    cout<<(char*)arg<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);
    return NULL;
}
```

---

Side note : if you have access to C++11 consider using `std::mutex` & `std::lock_guard` and `std::thread` instead.

Comment: And `std::lock_guard` to get automatic unlocking.

Comment: @NathanOliver I actually meant to type "Consider using `<thread>` and `<mutex>`" as in, the header files but I just typed the actual classes instead on accident, damn brain. Edited regardless, thanks.

Comment: No problem.  I just wanted the OP to be made aware we can make this automatic.  House keeping isn't fun and if we can make the compiler do it then it is a win for us all :)

Answer (score 3):

You should call [pthread_mutex_unlock](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_mutex_lock) to unlock the mutex and let the second thread to do the work:

```
void* tf(void*arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
    cout<<(char*)arg<<endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt); // <=== here
    return NULL;
}
```

If unlock is not performed then the second thread is waiting the mutex forever and the program "hangs".

If it is mandatory to use *pthreads* in your program then you might consider writing some *RAII* wrapper to avoid such bugs.

Answer (score 1):

You should unlock mutex to allow the 2nd thread execute tf() function. Now the mutex locked by the 1st thread(The 1st means the 1st which started ft() execution) and never unlocks. I also recommend to use something like std::lock_guard(never worked with pthread_mutex_t so don't know exact name) to avoid such problem